# Finding minimum value of function

Tags: functions, optimization

> let p,q,r be positive real numbers then least value of

$p(1+q)+ q(1+r)+ r(1+p)$/$(pqr)^{1/3}$

Ans=2

---

This question is from kvpy . There was no simplification by using A.M G.M inequality. Can someone provide me hint for this problem

Comment: Based on AM-GM, you can see $\frac{p(1+q)+ q(1+r)+ r(1+p)}{(pqr)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \gt 3$

Comment: Does [Lagrange Multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) not work?